# How to find and match an exact string in a column using AWK?

Tags: awk

I'm having trouble on matching an exact string that I want to find in a file using `awk`.

I have the file called "*sup_groups.txt*" that contains: 
(the structure is: "group_name:pw:group_id:user1<,user2>...")

```
adm:x:4:syslog,adm1
admins:x:1006:adm2,adm12,manuel
ssl-cert:x:122:postgres
ala2:x:1009:aceto,salvemini
conda:x:1011:giovannelli,galise,aceto,caputo,haymele,salvemini,scala,adm2,adm12
adm1Group:x:1022:adm2,adm1,adm3
docker:x:998:manuel
```

now, I want to extract the records that have in the user list the user "adm1" and print the first column (the group name), but you can see that there is a user called "adm12", so when i do **this**:

```
awk -F: '$4 ~ "adm1" {print $1}' sup_groups.txt
```

the output is:

```
adm
admins
conda
adm1Group
```

the command of course also prints those records that contain the string "adm12", but I don't want these lines because I'm interested only on the user "adm1".

So, How can I change this command so that it just prints the lines 1 and 6 (excluding 2 and 5)?

thank you so much and sorry for my bad English

**EDIT**: thank you for the answers, u gave me inspiration for the solution, i think this might work as well as your solutions but more simplified:

```
awk -F: '$4 ~ "adm,|adm1$|:adm1," {print $1}' sup_groups.txt
```

basically I'm using ORs covering all the cases and excluding the "adm12"
let me know if you think this is correct

Comment: You have 2 delimiters of `:` and `,` so which field you want to actually compare the values?

Comment: yeah i know, because that is the user list so it is considered as one single field. i use -F: because i know that i need to find "adm1" in the userlist

Comment: Line `adm:x:4:syslog,adm1` has 4 columns(excluding `,`) and line `admins:x:1006:adm2,adm12,manuel` also has 4 fields so you want to check if 4th field has `adm1` or not in any of its value?

Comment: i just want to check if 4th field contains the user"adm1" and then print that line, but the command that i use prints the lines that contain also the adm12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Using `split` function of `awk`. With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -F':' '
{
  num=split($4,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(arr[i]=="adm1"){
      print
    }
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -F':' '               ##Starting awk program from here setting field separator as : here.
{
  num=split($4,arr,",")   ##Using split to split 4th field into array arr with delimiter of ,
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){    ##Running for loop till value of num(total elements of array arr).
    if(arr[i]=="adm1"){   ##Checking condition if arr[i] value is equal to adm1 then do following.
      print               ##printing current line here.
    }
  }
}
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using regex and conditions in `awk`.

```
awk -F':' '$4~/^adm1,/ || $4~/,adm1,/ || $4~/,adm1$/' Input_file
```

***OR*** if 4th field doesn't have comma at all then try following:

```
awk -F':' '$4~/^adm1,/ || $4~/,adm1,/ || $4~/,adm1$/ || $4=="adm1"' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Making field separator as `:` and checking condition if 4th field is either equal to `^adm1,`(starting adm1,) OR its equal to `,adm1,` OR its equal to `,adm1$`(ending with ,adm1) then print that line.

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, this solutions is good but unfortunately i can't use the split built-in function

Comment: @sirducas, your welcome. but why can't you use `split` :)

Comment: @sirducas, Also for your EDIT question, your condition is much like what I shared, this mentioned one will be more easier for anyone to understand IMHO, cheers.

Comment: yeah you are right, but what if the line contains the one and only adm1 user? like "<...>:adm1" ? (without final comma, basically)

Comment: @sirducas, oh ok in that case try `awk -F':' '$4~/^adm1,/ || $4~/,adm1,/ || $4~/,adm1$/ || $4=="adm1"' Input_file`

Comment: yeah ok right, perfect. sorry i'm just a newbie on awk. thank you so much this command do the work.

Comment: @sirducas, that's not an issue, we all are here to learn, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: What if instead i want to count the number of users? for example, i want to print the number of users where the group name is equal to "conda" (so $1=="conda").
should i open another question?

Comment: @sirducas, could you please open a new question please. Its always recommended to ask 1 question 1 post please.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$ awk -F: '"," $4 "," ~ ",adm1," { print $1 }' file
```

The idea behind this is the encapsulate both the group field between commas such that each group entry is encapsulated by commas. So instead of searching for `adm1` you search for `,adm1,`

So if your list looks like:

```
adm2,adm12,manuel
```

and, by adding commas, you convert it too:

```
,adm2,adm12,manuel,
```

you can always search for `,adm1,` and find the perfect match .

Comment: hi, thanks so much, this is correct and i thank you, but i think i found a solution using some  logical ORs and covering some cases, like this:
awk -F: '$4 ~ "adm,|adm1$|:adm1," {print $1}' sup_groups.txt

Comment: @sirducas Your solution might still fail with cases like `badm1`

Comment: yea i found the error, your solution is better and do the work, but can you explain me the commas between " " ?

Comment: @sirducas I've added some more information.

Comment: oh i can convert the printing output so i know that every word ends with a comma, yeah that is also a perfect solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

once u setup `FS` per task requirements, then main body becomes barely just :

```
    NF = !_ < NF
```

or even more straight forward :

```
  {m,n,g}awk —- --NF
```

=

```
{m,g}awk 'NF=!_<NF' OFS= FS=':[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*[^[:alpha:]]?adm[0-9]+.*$' 

adm
admins
conda
adm1Group
```